# How to run Spark Java application on AWS?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, spark-java

I have developed an app using Spark Java Framework (www.sparkjava.com). I am able to build the artifact on my windows as a JAR file. I can confirm I am able to run it via command line "java -jar App.jar Main.java". It hosts a web app at localhost:4567.

What's the most convenient/quickest way to load this onto an AWS server? I created an EC2 instance (AMI Instance), copied over the jar file to it, ran the command. The log seems to run successfully, but I can't hit the DNS server. It doesn't seem to be up.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't hit the DNS server"? Do you mean that you can't connect to your server? If yes, then check that your EC2 instance's Security Group allows inbound connections to 4567 from your IP-address.

Comment: Thanks! That answered the question. Security Groups -> Inbound Ports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

1. Log into AWS
2. Click on Instances and click on your Instance
3. In description, see Security Groups, click on your Security Group
4. In the Inbound tab, click on Add Rule
5. Add HTTP, HTTPS, and Custom
6. For Custom, set the Port to the port that you'd like to be
   available to all incoming traffic. Hit apply.